# Writing this term in Span structure? Is this Basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the set {${ 1, x-1, x^2+1 }$} a basis for the vector space $P_2(\mathbb {R})$?

First time I am learning the concept and this problem looked a complex. I am having hard time on writing Span. This is linear independence( I found). But I couldn't write in Span structure.

Comment: $ax^2+bx+c = (-a+b+c)1+b(x-1)+a(x^2+1)$. What does this tells you?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: a=-a+b+c,b=b,a+c @azif00

Comment: @mathloveuu What?! Why? My point is: The polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ is the same as $(-a+b+c)1+b(x-1)+a(x^2+1)$ *for all* the values of $a,b$ and $c$.

Comment: So this term becomes a span? And this set becomes basis?

Answer (score 1):

So you have already proved linear independence of set $S=${${ 1, x-1, x^2+1 }$}. Now you want to check this set indeed spans whole $P_2(\mathbb {R})$.

Let $a,b,c$ be three scalars from given field.
So span of S,$L(S)$=$(a.1+b.(x-1)+c.(x^2+1)$   where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$
$L(S)$=$a-b+c+bx+c.x^2$.

Take $a-b+c=d$

$L(S)$=$d+bx+c.x^2$.

Clearly $S$ has spanned whole $P_2(\mathbb {R})$.

Answer (score 0):

A basis is a spanning linear independent list of a vector space. Since you have proved the linear independence, if you have learnt this theorem below:

> If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then any linearly independent list of length equal to its dimension is a basis of $V$.

then you may use the fact $\dim \mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R}) =3$ to show the list $(1,x-1,x^2+1)$ is a basis of $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$.